# Bidirectional Object-Conversation

Tags: java, generics, ejb

I have to process JPA-entity objects to JAXB-annotated objects and vis versa.

The two class types look like this:

```
@Entity
public Entity{
private String fieldA;
private int fieldB;
private Entity2 fieldC;
// + Getters and Setters
}

@RootElement
public JAXBEntity (extends AbstractJAXBEntity<Entity>){
private String fieldA;
private int fieldB;
private String fieldC;
// + Getters and Setters
public JAXBEntity(Entity entity) {...}
public Entity getEntity() {...}
}
```

What I need are methods for: `Entity <-> JAXBEntity, List<Entity> <-> List<JAXBEntity>`

I have a lot of those class-pairs, so I'm searching for a very generic solution with minimum individual implementation per pair. The optimum would be if I would need to implement only the `constructor` and `getEntity` in `JAXBEntity` per pair.

I thought up the following class structure:

```
public abstract class AbstractJAXBEntity<Entity>

@Stateless
public EntityConversation <JAXBEntity extends AbstractJAXBEntity>
```

The idea was that I could get the generics Type of `JAXBEntity` in a instance of `EntityConversation` and then the Type of `Entity`. When I have the types I can easily create objects by Reflections.

But due to [type-erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) this is a little bit complicated. 
Additionally `EntityConversation` can use a parameterless constructor only. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to inject it with `@EJB`.

Is this approach realistic and do you see any way I can get the types? Or is there a nice other way to do this I didn't see?

Comment: Why not use a single object model for both JPA and JAXB?

Comment: There are two main reasons: 

I need Data from related JPAEntitys but there are cycles in the realtions. So JAXB produces a StackOverflow. 

On the other side I need many different views of a JPAEntity which contain different subsets of the fields. So there may be several JAXBEntitys for one JPA Entity.

Comment: I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead and we have features designed to solve those problems `@XmlInverseReference` for bidirectional relationships (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlInverseReference) and object graphs for subsets (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/Object%20Graphs).

Comment: That sounds really interesting. I'll need to read up on it but I think it should provide all I need. Thx. But now I should really go to university otherwise I'll miss my exam. ;-)